# SQL CASE in WHERE clause with parameter

Tags: sql, switch-statement, where-clause

@status is a parameter to stored proc.Based on @Status, if @Status = 'Y' then just get Active records. if @Status = 'N' then fetch the records which have been deactivated less than 30 days back. We do not want to get deactivated records older than 30 days. Therefore, I need to put the logic in WHERE clause as follows. Please guide how to achieve this

```
    SELECT * from TableA
WHERE Active =
    ( CASE  @Status WHEN 'N' THEN ('N' AND CONVERT(DATE,ISNULL(DateDeactivated,'01/01/2016')) 
    BETWEEN  CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-30) AND CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
WHEN 'Y' THEN   'Y' ELSE 'Y' END)
```

Comment: which sql database?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is too complicated.  How about this?

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TableA a
WHERE (@Status = 'N' AND DateDeactivated >= CAST(GETDATE() - 30 as DATE) or
      (@Status = 'Y' AND DateDeactivated IS NULL)
```

I assume "active" records are those that have no deactivation date.

Comment: Active is a field which is either 'Y' or 'N'. DateDeactivated is a date field which represents the date the Active field was set to 'N' i.e. de-activated. So Active needs to be part of query